# How can I add line break as inner HTML systematically with ReactJS (+ Redux)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I have these codes, in one of my component: `<p>{ result }</p>`. `result` will be like `'asd\n123'`, generated programmatically.

However the result in browser is "asd 123". It seems, the line break is not well received as inner HTML. **How can I have "asd" and then line break and then "123" displayed in my web browser?**

Comment: This could be solved with setting the CSS `white-space: pre-wrap` on the `<p>`. That’s assuming there’s no other unsignificant white-space in your `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var result = 'asd' + (String.fromCharCode(13, 10) + 123;
<p>{ result }</p>
```

In ES6:

```
var result = `asd${String.fromCharCode(13, 10)}123`;
<p>{ result }</p>
```

Or you have to replace your \n:

```
result.split('\n').join(String.fromCharCode(13, 10));
<p>{ result }</p>
```

WORKING SNIPPET:

```js
var result = "some\nstring";
var res = result.split('\n').join(String.fromCharCode(13, 10));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @casraf's comment, I modified the codes into like this:

```
{ result != undefined ? result.split('\n').map(line => <p>{ line }</p>) : '' }
```

To solve this problem.